# How to fix Warning: call_user_func_array()?

Tags: functions, warnings

I modified my theme metabox.php to fit my needs, and I got this eror

> Blockquote Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mytheme_add_box' not found or invalid function name in E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 406 
>   Blockquote

How can i fix it ?

This is my old metabox code

```
<?php
$prefix = 'wtf_';

$meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'propertybox',
    'title' => 'Property listing details',
    'page' => 'listings',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
            array(
            'name' => 'Propert ID number',
            'desc' => 'Enter a property ID number, if any ',
            'id' => $prefix . 'pid',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),


        array(
            'name' => 'Bath',
            'desc' => 'Number of bathrooms.',
            'id' => $prefix . 'bath',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),

        array(
            'name' => 'An',
            'desc' => 'Anul constructiei',
            'id' => $prefix . 'an',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),      

        array(
            'name' => 'Etaj',
            'desc' => 'Etajul',
            'id' => $prefix . 'etaj',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),      

        array(
            'name' => 'Balcone',
            'desc' => 'Numar balcoane',
            'id' => $prefix . 'balcon',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),      

        array(
            'name' => 'Parcare',
            'desc' => 'Numar locuri de parcare',
            'id' => $prefix . 'parcare',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),      

        array(
            'name' => 'Suprafata totala',
            'desc' => 'Suprafata totala a terenului (Casa/vila)',
            'id' => $prefix . 'suprafatatotala',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),      

        array(
            'name' => 'Front stradal',
            'desc' => 'Suprafata front stradal',
            'id' => $prefix . 'front',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),      

        array(
            'name' => 'Suprafata curte libera ',
            'desc' => 'Suprafata curte libera ',
            'id' => $prefix . 'suprafatacurte',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),      

        array(
            'name' => 'Amprenta casei ',
            'desc' => 'Suprafata amprentei  ',
            'id' => $prefix . 'amprenta',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),      

        array(
            'name' => 'Regim inaltime',
            'desc' => 'Regim inaltime  ',
            'id' => $prefix . 'inaltime',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),      

        array(
            'name' => 'Certificat urbanism ',
            'desc' => 'certificat urbanism',
            'id' => $prefix . 'certificat',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),      

        array(
            'name' => 'Asking price',
            'desc' => 'Enter the actual asking price ',
            'id' => $prefix . 'price',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        )


    ),

);


add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box');

// Add meta box
function mytheme_add_box() {
    global $meta_box;

    add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'mytheme_show_box', $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}

// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function mytheme_show_box() {
    global $meta_box, $post;

    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="mytheme_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

    echo '<table class="form-table">';

    foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        // get current post meta data
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

        echo '<tr>',
                '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
                '<td>';
        switch ($field['type']) {
            case 'text':
                echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />',
                    '<br />', $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                echo '<textarea class="theEditor" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>',
                    '<br />', $field['desc'];

                break;
            case 'select':
                echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<option', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>',
                '<br />', $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'radio':
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
                }
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
                break;
        }
        echo    '<td>',
            '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data');

// Save data from meta box
function mytheme_save_data($post_id) {
    global $meta_box;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mytheme_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

And this is my new code

```
<?php
$prefix = 'wtf_';

$property_fields = array(
         array(
            'name' => 'Propert ID number',
            'desc' => 'Enter a property ID number, if any ',
            'id'   =>   $prefix.'pid',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std'   => ''
         ),
         array(
            'name' => 'Bath',
            'desc' => 'Number of bathrooms.',
            'id'   => $prefix.'bath',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std'  => ''
         ),      
         array(
             'name' => 'An',
             'desc' => 'Anul constructiei',
             'id'   => $prefix.'an',
             'type' => 'text',
             'std'  => ''
         ));

$mansion_fields = array(    

    array(
        'name' => 'Etaj',
        'desc' => 'Etajul',
        'id' => $prefix . 'etaj',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    ),      

    array(
        'name' => 'Balcone',
        'desc' => 'Numar balcoane',
        'id' => $prefix . 'balcon',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    ),      

    array(
        'name' => 'Parcare',
        'desc' => 'Numar locuri de parcare',
        'id' => $prefix . 'parcare',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    ),      

    array(
        'name' => 'Suprafata totala',
        'desc' => 'Suprafata totala a terenului (Casa/vila)',
        'id' => $prefix . 'suprafatatotala',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    ),      

    array(
        'name' => 'Front stradal',
        'desc' => 'Suprafata front stradal',
        'id' => $prefix . 'front',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    ),      

    array(
        'name' => 'Suprafata curte libera ',
        'desc' => 'Suprafata curte libera ',
        'id' => $prefix . 'suprafatacurte',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    ),      

    array(
        'name' => 'Amprenta casei ',
        'desc' => 'Suprafata amprentei  ',
        'id' => $prefix . 'amprenta',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    ),        

    array(
        'name' => 'Regim inaltime',
        'desc' => 'Regim inaltime  ',
        'id' => $prefix . 'inaltime',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    ),      

    array(
        'name' => 'Certificat urbanism ',
        'desc' => 'certificat urbanism',
        'id' => $prefix . 'certificat',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    ),      

    array(
        'name' => 'Asking price',
        'desc' => 'Enter the actual asking price ',
        'id' => $prefix . 'price',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    ));

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_meta_boxes' );
function my_meta_boxes(){
    //Don't forget to change "post" with post_type where you want to add the metaboxes
    add_meta_box("propertybox", "Property Options", "propertybox", "listings", "normal", "high");
    add_meta_box("mansionbox", "Mansion Options", "mansionbox", "listings", "normal", "high");
 }

function propertybox(){
    global $prefix;
    global $property_fields;
   //Put here the fields you want display inside the "Property options" box.
    build_fieds($property_fields);
}

function mansionbox(){
    global $prefix;
    global $mansion_fields;

    build_fieds($mansion_fields);
}

function build_fieds($fields){
     global $post;

     echo '<table class="form-table">';

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    // get current post meta data
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

    echo '<tr>',
            '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
        '<td>';
    switch ($field['type']) {
        case 'text':
            echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />',
            '<br />', $field['desc'];
            break;
        case 'textarea':
            echo '<textarea class="theEditor" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>',
            '<br />', $field['desc'];

            break;
        case 'select':
            echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                echo '<option', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
        }
            echo '</select>',
        '<br />', $field['desc'];
            break;
        case 'radio':
            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
        }
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
            break;
    }
    echo    '<td>',
        '</tr>';
}

 echo '</table>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data');

// Save data from meta box
function mytheme_save_data($post_id) {

    global $mansion_fields;
    global $property_fields;

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ($property_fields as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
     }

    foreach ($mansion_fields as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

       if ($new && $new != $old) {
           update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
       } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
           delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
       }
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: call_user_func_array()  is calling this mytheme_add_box function but cant find on your script

Comment: i understand that, what i don't understand is why is calling that function because in my new code i am not using mytheme_add_box.

Comment: yes thats kind of weird are you sure you executed script only after saving it ?

Comment: Yes, because if i use my old code i am not getting that error and my property listing details and mansion listings details appear as one. Could it be because of an plug in ?

Comment: Try deactivating all plugins.

Comment: i deactivated all my plugins, and still the same problem, maybe it is a theme problem

Comment: Try to search for mytheme_add_box in all your theme/plugin files. mytheme_add_box is obviously called from some where but not from the code you posted

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will help but after dealing with the exact same error message for the last 2 days I finally figured out what was happening. **It was simply a matter of attempting to call the function before the system knew it existed.**

In my case, I had written the function in a separate--not-publicly-accessible--directory and attempted to call this function in my `functions.php` file before I even included the file that contained the function.

Inside my `custom_funcs.php` file was this function:

```
function my_custom_funk($url, $path = '', $plugin = '') {
    $host = get_this_cust_url( $url );
    $url = str_replace( parse_url( WP_PLUGIN_URL, PHP_URL_HOST ), $host, $url );
    return $url;
}
```

Inside of my `functions.php` file, I was doing this:

```
// get the funk
add_filter( 'plugins_url', 'my_custom_funk' );

// Load Custom Functions
include( '/my/non-public/path/custom_funcs.php' );
```

Once I changed their order to this...

```
// Load Custom Functions
include( '/my/non-public/path/custom_funcs.php' );

// get the funk
add_filter( 'plugins_url', 'my_custom_funk' );
```

...the error completely stopped.

Hopefully this helps and saves someone two days of debugging.

Lastly, the posts read [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/call_user_func_array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-valid-custom-function/) are what lead me to make the change.